# Another c-wire challenge

Tags: electrical, thermostat-c-wire

Opened the furnace to find this situation:
Red and white coming in from the left are from the thermostat.

Yellow wire nut is labeled C. Other end is in the circuit board.

What do I connect the C-wire to?

(Yes, when I redo this I will fix the connections that are just tape.)
[image: Furnace wiring]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found it. You'll connect the C wire to an unused wire in your thermostat cable. If you only have 4 wires (for heat and cool) or 2 wires (for heat only), you will need to replace your thermostat cable with one with more conductors.